# Legal concern over "borrowed" code

Tags: legal, ethics, code-reuse

A company my friend works for (let's call him Me) recently unveiled a new face for their internal "networking" website. This new face looks remarkably like Facebook, and indeed, examination of the source code reveals that it's almost identical: The code, class names, and even the fonts are the same. There is also no indication that Facebook is in any way involved or aware.

I know this is unethical, but is it illegal? I can't find anything concrete about this to help Me decide what to do about it.

EDIT: We're talking front-end code. It does not appear to be linking to Facebook in any way.

Comment: You're referring to front-end code? If so, make it clear in your question.

Comment: Legal questions should always be answered by picking up the phone and calling a lawyer, not posting them to be answered by random people on the internet.

Comment: Is there any licensing info available from Facebook?

Comment: It's only borrowed you if intend to return it. Otherwise, it's stolen.

Comment: @vartec: yes, front-end code. I will edit. @Frustrated: I couldn't find any. I know Facebook isn't shy about integrating FB into other websites, but it usually has the Facebook logo and not some bogus new logo. It doesn't appear to link up to FB's backend. @Michael: Sometimes, random internet people are all you have. Me's contacted the legal dept.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

> I know this is unethical, but is it illegal?

If you're asking this question, I think you already know what the proper course of action is.